# Run Ubuntu terminal from bin folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

So, I uninstalled Python and now my Ubuntu GUI interface is quite messed up. I really can't seem to do anything, but I've accessed the file system from right-clicking a file I created and choosing "run-as filesystem". I need to get to the terminal, but it is not listed as a run-as application. I know I can run many programs from the /usr/bin directory. Does anyone know the name of the script in that directory that would run the terminal? I'm running Ubuntu LTS 12.04.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to switch to a different terminal (using Control-Alt-F1), log in there and then install Python again.  Since `apt-get` is a binary it does not need any Python installed, so you should be able to install it using

```
apt-get install python
```

After this (and maybe a reboot for fixing several boot-time problems) you should be able to log in normally again.